# Is it haram to continue watching a movie/series after it shows something offensive about Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, movies, tv

If for I watch a show or a movie which has a line which is offensive about our religion or any scene which we shouldn't see. Is it haram for me to watch the rest of the seasons or the movie even though I never intended to listen or watch those things and I hide it, skip it or close my eyes when the bad scene comes and I seek Allah's forgiveness too?

Comment: Authentic hadith: whoever withholds for the sake of Allah has perfected imaan

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](//islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](//islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in our [help center](//islam.stackexchange.com/help). Can you be a bit more specific? What do you mean by "offensive about religion"? What do you mean about "scenes which we shouldn't see"?

Answer (score -1):

I will give you an answer based on my specific knowledge derived from a variety of sources, being an expert in Netzerim Islam.  Firstly, there is a tradition in certain countries with a significant pro-Mohammadean populace to declare television and movies unlawful.  In Western countries this is not the case.  I have watched a documentary this very night (Media on the Brain-Conformed or Transformed, beltoftruthministries.org) dealing with the subject of the effect of media on society, by the American Christian assembly, the Seventh-Day Adventists.  The documentary reported some very negative impacts on individuals, and society, which support the position of certain hardline proponents of Islam.  For instance, the introduction of television broadcasting to Canada, the United States, and South Africa coincided with an approximate twofold increase in murder rates.  Apparently France now has guidelines in place to reduce the exposure of children to television.  One particular study linked regular exposure to television to a reduction in life expectancy.  Apparently the visual medium stimulates the brain in an identical way to addictive forms of behaviour.  This causes profound physical and psychological changes.  One example, news, when watched, this has profound effects, as noted, but when read in, say, a newspaper, there is no matching result.  In other words, the human brain is formed in a unique way, which inevitably responds in a negative way to such stimuli.  Therefore **there is no safe exposure to television, or movies**, etc.  This is then a case of user beware!  Since television and other media did not exist until modern times, **there is no prophetic statement on the matter**.  Regarding a specific show, which may mimic conditions in the real world, **it would be prudent to apply the same rules you would use as an observer in an analogous situation.**

Comment: How on earth is this an answer ? The question was about a specific show, not about how much time one should spend watching TV in order to avoid side effects. And pick better sources than 7th day adventists please, there is actual research done on this (which the French health commitees probably used)

Comment: Anonymous user, you state that "the French health commitees probably used",  "actual research".  I have stated clearly the source which I used, and you are free to investigate the research used by the makers of the documentary.  Acting on an assumption through a prejudicial basis is not an appropriate response.  http://beltoftruthministries.org/media-on-the-brain/ is the link, see disc1.